# Define gdalwarp tile size

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

gdalwarp has `-co TILES=YES` (256x256 as default)

Can I set different tile size?

Comment: From http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html, the correct `gdalwarp` option is `-co TILED=YES`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with `-co "BLOCKXSIZE=n"` and `-co "BLOCKYSIZE=n"`, but beware that not all formats support blocks with a height > 1.